# Extract the correct month from timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

got stuck in extracting the correct month from timestamp...Here's my Code

```
$sql = "SELECT id,notice,description,DAY( `posted_date` ) AS DAY, MONTH(`posted_date` ) AS MONTH, YEAR( `posted_date`) AS YEAR, enable FROM n_notice";
                                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                                while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                                {
                                    $notice = $run['notice'];   
                                    $description = $run['description'];

                                    $day =$run['DAY'];
                                    //$month=$run['MONTH'];
                                    $month=date("M",$run['MONTH']);
                                    $year=$run['YEAR'];
                            ?>

                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                    <div id="date">
                                        <div class="mon"><?php echo $month;?></div>
                                        <div class="day"><?php echo $day;?></div>
                                        <div class="year"><?php echo $year;?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h5 class="media-heading"><?php echo $notice; ?></h5>
                                    <?php echo $description; ?>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                }
                                // Free result set
                                mysqli_free_result($result);
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

### DB timestamp column

[image]

How to get the correct month in "M" format? All the Months are shown as "Jan"!!!

Comment: how about `.. MONTHNAME(posted_date ) AS MONTH ..`

Comment: ...and this is what i did left(MONTHNAME(`posted_date` ),3)

Comment: odd, whats the field type for `posted_date` ??

Comment: oh you just want the first 3 letters, i get it

Comment: This -> MONTHNAME(posted_date ) AS MONTH gives January and This -> left(MONTHNAME(posted_date ),3) gives me Jan or May or Oct, for which i required! But hey Thanks again

Comment: the alternative (for completeness) is `DATE_FORMAT(psoted_date,'%M')`

Comment: ...but my date is showing only single digit instead of two? any fixes?

Comment: use lowercase "%m" in DATE_FORMAT. it will return 2 Digit month see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/date_format/

Comment: it didn't work....but this does the trick -> LEFT(DATE_FORMAT( `posted_date`,'%M' ),3)

Comment: i thought this is solved- are you saying its not @shaiToro ?

Answer (score 0):

> $month=date("M",$run['MONTH']);

Try to change "M" to "F".

F - A full textual representation of a month (January through December)